# Which thread will timer method run in?

Tags: c#, multithreading, timer

I looking to run a method periodically but would like to optimise my code by having it run in a separate thread. So far my code looks something like below:

```
private System.Timers.Timer timerQuartSec = new System.Timers.Timer(250);
private Thread quarterSecThread;

timerQuartSec.Elapsed += new System.Timers.ElapsedEventHandler(someMethod);

quarterSecThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(timerQuartSec.Start));
```

My question is, would this code simply start the timer or would the code (on TimerElapsed) run on the new Thread?

Comment: This may help you http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc164015.aspx

Comment: @K.B I understand it won't run. This is just a snippet. First two lines are variable declarations before the actual methods.

Comment: Thanks @HamletHakobyan. Great read, definitely helped me understand the difference between Timer types. Luckily I was using the right one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`System.Timers.Timer` will run on a `ThreadPool` thread as long as you don't set the timer's `SynchronizingObject`.

So there's no need to start a dedicated thread. You need to pay attention though if you want to access GUI elements.

Comment: Only if `SynchronizingObject` is set accordingly - which it isn't in the snippet. I add this piece of information to the answer.

Comment: Seems to make sense. If the timer is automatically assigned to a separate thread then all should be fine...then again that means that another part of the program is causing lag! Thanks @JeffRSon